# using C# for creating a stored procedure

Tags: c#, stored-procedures

I want to define one stored procedure having 2 tables that insert into the first table and updates the second table. The first table contains the PostID and the PersonID, the second table contains postID and Counter. Would you please help me correct this one? I know this is not correct.

```
com.CommandText = @"CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.Facebook @PostID int,@PerosnalID int, 
                   BEGIN 
                         INSERT dbo.Like (PostID) VALUES (@PersonalID), 
                         UPDATE dbo.Counter (Counter) 
                            SET PostID = @value1 
                          WHERE Counter = Sum @PersonalID 
                   END";
```

Comment: your SQL makes no sense to me.  You have a table named "Like"?  and what's up with your UPDATE statement?

Comment: @ t McKeown yes one table named like and another table named Counter. This is supposed to act like when you like a post on facebook. on one table there is the postID and yourID and i want this table to show me for example postID =2 , PersonID = 6523 ; and the other table saves the PostID = 2 , Counter = 4 ( means postID =2 has been liked 4 times) , i need one store procedure to do this insert and update for me .inserting into first table and updating the second table.

Comment: @user3158098 Can you please elaborate on what exactly goes wrong? It is not clear what the exact problem is.

Comment: Like is a reserved word in most SQL dialects. It's a really bad idea to use a reserved word as a table name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's start and fix the procedure syntax:

```
com.CommandText = "CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.Facebook( @PostID int,@PersonalID int) AS "+
                  " INSERT dbo.[Like] (PostID) VALUES (@PersonalID); " +
                  " UPDATE C SET Counter = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dbo.[Like] WHERE PostId = @PersonalID)" +
                  " FROM dbo.Counter AS C " +
                  " WHERE C.PostID = @PersonalID  ";
```

Comment: My second table needs to be updated each time someone likes a post and updates the counter(the counter table shows for example postID =2 counter =7  has been liked 7 times) , but i don't know how to write this piece of code

Comment: Ok, I will modify my answer.

Comment: see if that works... pretty sure i understand your request.  =)

Comment: Dude i have an error now saying Must declare the scalar variable "@PersonalID".

Comment: your declaration is misspelled, you have it PerosnalID on the declaration but spelled correctly when in the query.  I corrected the answer.

Comment: did it work?  please up vote or show as answer if it did.  thanks!